# why is start time greater than end time

Tags: php, performance

I have the following code to calculate the execution time.

```
$TimeTaken['start'] = microtime();
require_once 'resources/include.php'; 
session_start();

ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);*/
error_reporting(0);

/* Other Mojo
  ...............
  ...............
  ...............
*/

ob_flush();
flush();
ob_end_flush();

$TimeTaken['end']   = microtime();
$TimeTaken['diff'] = $TimeTaken['end'] - $TimeTaken['start'];
print_r($TimeTaken);
?>
```

This is the output that i got (sometimes)

```
Array ( [start] => 0.72150600 1329728036 
        [end] => 0.62957200 1329728038 
        [diff] => -0.091934 )
```

Is the above code right and if so why is start time > end time

Comment: This is what happens when you do optimization in a DeLorean.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the **valid** way to get the time with microseconds is `microtime(true);`, not `microtime();`

Without second parameter equal to `true` you just have a string `0.72150600 1329728036` that represents the second fractions and seconds since unix epoch separated by space. And subtraction operator just casts it to the `0.72150600` which is just wrong.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to use `time()` instead .

Comment: Sure no reason , but it's more easier as it returns a straight value , and it could be used in other functions like `mktime` and so on .

Comment: 1. it doesn't return second fractions, so it is useless for intervals <= 1 second 2. `mktime` doesn't accept unix timestamp, it accepts just integers for each datetime fraction

Comment: Check the manual , and do your tests and back to me , thank you for your replies .

Comment: Already checked `http://php.net/mktime` --- would you be so kind to point me where `mktime` accepts unix timestamp as a parameter?

Comment: First of all I didn't say your answer is incorrect(gave you +1 BTW) ... now back to our conversation , i didn't say it could be used as a PARAMETER in `mktime` , i meant it could be used as the effect of other function , for example , you can use it in something like `date("Y-m-d",time())` ... second thing , if the user doesn't require the millisecond value , `time()` will be more easier .. again thank you for your replies (and your -1)

Comment: The `microtime(true)` result can be used with `date` as well. So about `mktime` - I still cannot see how `mktime` is even related to `time` or `microtime`. You're welcome.

Comment: `echo date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,12,12,12));` so here we can pass `mktime` or `time`